# WP shortcode inside html tags

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

I need to update a bunch of forms with options like this one regularly:

```
<option value="Asym. Spinnaker Std colors Size 4{p:1000usd|c:US-SPI-FSASY|y:US-SPI-S}">Std. Color Asym. Spinnaker – Size 4 – $ 1000</option>
```

I created a short code that reads the data that need updating off a .csv file and "should" update the form:

```
<option value="Asym. Spinnaker Std colors Size 4{p:[price line = "2" column = "5"]usd|c:US-SPI-FSASY|y:US-SPI-S}">Std. Color Asym. Spinnaker – Size 4 – $ [price line = "2" column = "5"]</option>
```

Unfortunately, short codes are not interpreted inside of tags, and only the second instance of the shortcode works - the first one is just rendered as is:

```
<option value="Asym. Spinnaker Std colors Size 4{p:[price line = "2" column = "5"]usd|c:US-SPI-FSASY|y:US-SPI-S}">Std. Color Asym. Spinnaker – Size 4 – $ 1000</option>
```

Any idea how (1)  I can make this work, or (2)perhaps a suggestion of a different mechanism to update  those forms without using  a shortcode ?

Comment: Write shortcode to output the entire option tag is one way. Or simply make the entire form field or form with code. it depends on how you are setting this entire structure. You should explain your system, at least if these are custom post types, pages, and what plugins you are using, etc... More description would usually help.

Comment: This came to my mind - and  I wrote the shortcode, to return the full html line  , but what I get isa a string, not as executable html (i.e. within quotes like this:

Comment: "<option>  stuff  </option>"

 - how can i get rid of those     "  ?

Comment: Show your code for the shortcode you created?

Comment: Here it is -  note I have not completely developed the return item - just enough to concatenate fixed parts of the stings, and the ones that are sad from the priceless.csv file

function price_shortcode( $atts ) {
 // Attributes
 $atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
   'line' => '',
   'column' => '',
  ),
  $atts,
  'price'
 );

 // loads PriceList.csv file into array
 ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

Comment: $PriceListArray = array();
 if (($handle = fopen("wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/pa/PriceList.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $PriceListArray[] = $data;
  }
  fclose($handle);
 }
 ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", false);

// Return content of price list at specified location in css file
 $targetline = $atts['line'] - 1;
 $targetcolumn = $atts['column'] - 1;


  return 'test'.$PriceListArray[$targetline][$targetcolumn].'othertest';

}
add_shortcode( 'price', 'price_shortcode' );

Comment: If you could, can you edit your post with the comments. It's hardly readable right now.

Comment: Sorry -  I did not realize it would come out this ugly. I created a paste bin to display the quote cleanly - the comment I made above stands: "I have not completely developed the return item - just enough to concatenate some fixed elements with variables


https://pastebin.com/Sgzprdr3

Answer (score 0):

[Shortcodes do not evaluate within HTML attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/241637/77028). It is a security feature to prevent poor coding practice and cross-site scripting vulnerabilities (XSS). If you want to bypass it, you need to add a PHP tag and `do_shortcode` call within the attribute **(WARNING: be careful to property sanitize anything you add to tag attributes!)**.

```php
<?php
$valueAttrContent = do_shortcode('Asym. Spinnaker Std colors Size 4{p:[price line = "2" column = "5"]usd|c:US-SPI-FSASY|y:US-SPI-S}');
$innerHTML = do_shortcode('Std. Color Asym. Spinnaker – Size 4 – $ [price line = "2" column = "5"]');

?><option value="<?= $valueAttrContent ?>"><?= $innerHTML ?></option>
```

Comment: thanks for you reply - but  thought  I could not use PhP within a WP page ? do you mean I should use seem plug in like  "insert php"  ?

Comment: I didn't know you were referring to the editor. I thought you meant you were trying to implement via a template file. If you are using the editor then this answer will not work.

Comment: I don't recommend ever using a plugin that allows you to insert PHP into content. That is like asking to be hacked.